# add column db-mgirate node

Tags: node.js, database-migration

I'm trying to add columns using node package db-migrate

Going through the docs, I can see how to create a table, and update data, but I don't see anything that lets me add a column to a table already in existence.

```
db.createTable('pets', {
id: { type: 'int', primaryKey: true },
name: 'string'
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

db-migrate SQL-Api has an `addColumn` method.

```
exports.up = function(db, callback) {
  db.addColumn('customers', 'firstname', { type: 'string' }, callback);
};
```

This would add a column `firstname` to table `customers`.

Please have a look in [docs](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/SQL/#addcolumntablename-columnname-columnspec-callback) for details.